# Pushing git tags from bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: git, jgit, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-pipelines, axion-release-plugin

I would like to use `axion-release-plugin` which is adding tags to git repository.

Now I would like to find a way to make git able to push tags from bitbucket pipeline.

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it's quite straightforward.

In when running gradle task from command line I need to add `-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=29418`

It's because bitbucket introduced new way to interact with git repository:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipelines-articles/Pushing-back-to-your-repository/ba-p/958407